# vue3-electron production build facing webpackJsonp not defined problem

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to build an electron app from a vue-cli3 project. The vue project itself works fine both in development and production. Everything works as well if I run a dev mode with `npm run electron:serve`. But the built electron app would give a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webpackJsonp' of undefined` in each packed js file.

vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: config => {
        const tsLoader = config.module.rules.find((loader) => loader.test === /\.ts$/);
        const tsLoaderIndex = config.module.rules.indexOf(tsLoader);
        const webWorkerLoader = {
            test: /\.worker\.ts$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'worker-loader',
                    options: {
                        filename: 'WorkerName.[hash].js',
                        inline: 'fallback',
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        config.module.rules = [...config.module.rules.slice(0, tsLoaderIndex-1), webWorkerLoader, ...config.module.rules.slice(tsLoaderIndex-1)]
        // console.log(config.module.rules);
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            config.mode = 'production'
            // pack dependencies separately
            let optimization = {
                runtimeChunk: 'single',
                splitChunks: {
                    chunks: 'all',
                    maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
                    minSize: 20000,
                    cacheGroups: {
                        vendor: {
                            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                            name (module) {
                                // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                                // or node_modules/packageName
                                const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1]
                                // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                                return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Object.assign(config, {
                optimization
            })
        }
    },

    parallel: false,

    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.output.globalObject('this')
    },

    pluginOptions: {
      'style-resources-loader': {
        preProcessor: 'scss',
        patterns: []
      }
    },

    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            less: {
                lessOptions: {
                    modifyVars: {
                        'font-size-base': '18px'
                    },
                    javascriptEnabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },

    devServer: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8080,
        public: 'localhost:8080',
      }
}
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "testApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons-vue": "^6.0.1",
    "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.3.4",
    "ant-design-vue": "^2.2.8",
    "bioseq": "^0.1.5",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "echarts": "^5.3.3",
    "idb-keyval": "^5.1.3",
    "jszip": "^3.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "pako": "^1.0.11",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.4",
    "vue3-infinite-scroll-good": "^1.0.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@types/electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/pako": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "electron": "^13.6.9",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "less-loader": "^7.3.0",
    "style-resources-loader": "^1.4.1",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader": "~0.1.5",
    "worker-loader": "^3.0.8"
  }
}
```

There are some instructions that it may be caused by something wrong with the webpack configuration. But I can only find examples in vue-cli2 webpack.prod.conf.js. How do we modify that in vue-cli3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the clue at https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/1706

There was a mistype 'this' in one of my vue templates causing the error. Removing that fixed the problem.